# Yii2 validate existencies in model

Tags: model, yii2

For my software, I have to prevent a user from selling more stocks than they find in the database, so to start, I have the stock field set as an unsigned integer.

The problem is that although these units cannot be sold and subtracted, the sale is generated without stock, because it is not validated.

To make the sale, I have three models corresponding to three tables in the database: Stock, detail of sale and sale.

To validate, create some functions so that the registered data of the tables are found in the database as follows:

```
public function getDetails()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Articledetail::className(), ['ID_ARTICLE_DETAIL' => 'ID_ARTICLE_DETAIL']);
}

public function getExistences()
{
    if ($mother = Articledetail::findOne($this->mother))
    {
        return $mother->details->ARTICLE_STOCK;
    }
}
```

Then, it should be possible to validate the model with the following rule:

```
public function rules()
{

    return [
        ['STOCK', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'existences', 'operator' => '<='],
    ];
}
```

The problem is that I think that you are not getting the integer value of the table in the database, because in the form, it doesn't matter what value you enter, it always says that it must be less than or equal to the existences function.

Comment: according to docs when the validator is being used to validate an attribute, the default value of this property would be the name of the attribute suffixed with `_repeat`. For example, if the attribute being validated is `password`, then this property will default to `password_repeat`. so i dont think you are correctly following the docs in you rule

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam You are wrong. Attribute suffixed with `_repeat` is only used if neither `compareAttribtue` nor `compareValue` are specified. He did specify the `compareAttribute`.

Comment: aah i found it you are right its in the code sample on the reference docs i overlooked it my bad

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in client side validation. The client side validation of `\yii\validators\CompareValidator` is designed to compare two input fields but you have nothing to compare with. In your case probably the best option is to skip the client side validation for this rule and only use this rule during server side validation. To do that set `$enableClientValidation` property to false in your rule definition like this:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [
            'STOCK',
            'compare',
            'compareAttribute' => 'existences',
            'operator' => '<=',
            'enableClientValidation' => false,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Also having a method that returns some value in if branch and has no return in main branch is a bad practice and it invites bugs. In your `getExistences` you should return some default value (for example 0) or throw an exception when nothing is found by `findOne`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  return [
      ['STOCK',
          function ($attribute) {
              if ($this->$attribute >= $yourModelexistences::find()....) { //Get the amount of existences from the database
                  $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'The amount is...'));
              }
          }
      ]
```

**Or**

```
protected $_existences;

public function rules()
{
  ['STOCK',
      function ($attribute) {
          if ($this->_existences === null || $this->attribute >= $this->_existences->existences) {
              $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user','The amount is Greater ..'));
          }
      }
  ]

    public function beforeValidate()
    {
        if (parent::beforeValidate()) {
            $this->_existences = existencesModel::findOne($STOCK_id); //Change according to your model and codes 
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Or**

```
public function rules()
{
       return [
            ['STOCK', 'compare', 'compareValue' => $yourModelexistences::find()...., 'operator' => '>='],
    ]
}
#code ...
```